# change from javascript browser alert to an html popup

Tags: javascript, forms, error-handling

I am a little out of my league for this one.
I have a form that validates each field individually, and does a standard alert with a specific message. Now I need to change the standard alert to be an alert message held within a hidden div in the html with the alert message.(client side)

not sure where to begin and any guidance would be appreciated.

```
if(el != null) {
                switch(el.name) {
                    case "firstName":              
                        //First Name Field Validation, Return false if field is empty
                        if( f.firstName.value == "" )
                        {
                            alert( bnadd_msg_002 );
                            if ((typeof TeaLeaf != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client.tlAddEvent != "undefined") ) {
                                var nVO = { ErrorMessage : bnadd_msg_002} 
                                var subtype="CustomErrorMsg";
                                TeaLeaf.Event.tlAddCustomEvent(subtype, nVO);
                                    }
                            return false; 
                        }
                        break;
```

Comment: You cannot really replace the browsers alert box by inserting an element because `alert` is blocking. An ugly alternative is using [showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) but that is a even a worse approach in performance terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function which changes the content of the div, then absolutely positions it in the middle of the screen. call that function where you use alert. This "alert box" will also need some sort of close button. When you load your scripts you should add an event which hides the div to the close button.

Some pseudo/real code in jQuery/javascript:

```
function betterAlert(msg){
  var jAlert = $('#myAlertDiv'), jWindow = $(window);
  var nHeight = jWindow.height();
  var nWidth = jWindow.width();
  var nAlertHeight = jAlert.height();
  var nAlertWidth = jAlert.width();
  jAlert.css({top:((nWidth-nAlertWidth)/2)+'px',left:((nHeight -nAlertHeight )/2)+'px'});
  jAlert.html(msg);
  jAlert.show();
}
function closeAlert(){
  $('#myAlertDiv').hide();
}
$('body, a.close').click(closeAlert);
```

And, of course style the div to your hearts content using css.

Another option, if you prefer libraries, is to use jQueryUI dialog. I'm sure just about any library out there has a similar functionality. You would just create a div with the alert message and call $('#myAlertDiv').dialog(). The drawback with libraries, as always, is that they will be a little slower than code you could write, because the library needs to support a lot more functionality than you need.

Comment: No close button. The design specs call for the error display to go away on focus

Comment: How would I accomplish this without a close button?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the comments. You'd set the closeAlert function in the focus event of the body (probably better if you did it on click rather than focus). I would still have a close button, users will be looking for it. If you get them a dialog without a close button they'll probably be confused. You can have both (close button and close on focus).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite the default `window.alert` method.

```
window.alert = function( text ) {
    createAWonderfulDialog( text );
};
```

Even if I usually don't suggest to overwrite/change any buildin methods, this one is an exception. Oldish browser still lock up the complete browser with a modal dialog, which is totally outdated.

So go on, do it!